# Predicate Logic and Logic Proofs(Review & Homework Questions)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic

I'm working on some homework questions and I am struggling very hard with the logic proofs. I might have an incorrect answer for 1 of the predicate questions but I think my question makes some sort of sense. I think I have more of an issue with the logic proofs, any help or hints would be great. Thanks!

***Logic Proof Questions***

Decide whether the inferences are valid in each case. Show every step.

1)

(p V q) -> r

p

.'. r

2)

p -> r

p v q

~q

.'.r

1.

```
  (p v q) -> r

  ~(p v q) v r (using p - > q = ~p v q (logical equiv))

  ~(p) v r     (using p - > (p v q)  (Addition Inference Rule))  <- is this correct?

  This is where I got lost, I don't know how to get from that statement to r.
```

2.

```
  p -> r

  ~(p) v r   (using p - > q = ~p v q (logical equiv))

  (p -> q) ^ (q -> r)  (using ( (p -> q) ^ (q -> r) ) -> (p -> r) (hypothetical syllogism)

  (p -> q) ^ (~q v r)  ( using logic equiv)

  ~p v r (using modens tollens)

  This is where i got lost, also i think i used the rules wrong
```

***Predicate Logic Questions***

1) The equation x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0 has no solutions over the natural numbers.

2) Every positive real number has a unique positive real square root.

1. ( ∀x :   | : (∄y :   | :  (x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0) = y) )
2. ( ∀x : ℝ | x > 0 : (Ǝy : ℝ | y > 0 : y^2 = x) )   (is this unique?)

I'd appreciate any help, I think i would need more help for the logic proof questions than the predicate questions because I am very lost on how to move from a statement to a different statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For 1) : $(p \lor q) \rightarrow r, p \vdash r$

we have :

1) $(p \lor q) \rightarrow r$ --- 1st premise

2) $p$ --- 2nd premise

3) $\lnot (p \lor q) \lor r$ --- from 1)

4) $p \lor q$ --- from 2) and the law : $\vdash p \rightarrow (p \lor q)$, by *modus ponens*

5) $r$ --- from 3) and 4) and *disjunctive syllogism* : from $\lnot A \lor B$ and $A$, infer : $B$.

> For 2) : $p \rightarrow r, p \lor q, \lnot q \vdash r$

we have :

1) $p \rightarrow r$ --- 1st premise

2) $p \lor q$ --- 2nd premise

3) $\lnot q \rightarrow p$ --- from 2)

4) $\lnot q \rightarrow r$ --- from 3) and 1) by *syllogism* : from $A \rightarrow B$ and $B \rightarrow C$, infer : $A \rightarrow C$

5) $\lnot q$ --- 3rd premise

6) $r$ --- from 4) and 5) by *modus ponens*.

---

For the *predicate logic* questions, I think that you have to translate them into formulae ...

If so, 1) must be :

> $\lnot \exists n \in \mathbb N [(x+1)^2=0]$.

For 2:

> $\forall x \in \mathbb R(x > 0 \rightarrow (\exists! y \in \mathbb R (y > 0 \land y^2 = x)))$.

Comment: Thanks Mauro I really appreciate it. I will study this and try to understand so I can get these answers correct next time.

Comment: Hi just wondering what inference rule is "Assumption"? because I can't find it in my book anywhere

Comment: Because you jump from one statement to another using assumption but I don't know how you get that idea

Comment: Name of my book is "McGraw Hill.Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 7th Edition" I'm not sure if i can use the assumption rule but I will email my profesor and ask.

Comment: Another way od solving 1) is : after step 2 : $¬(p∨q)∨r$ apply De Morgan to get : $(\lnot p \land \lnot q)∨r$ and then distributivity : $(\lnot p \lor r) \land (\lnot q \lor r)$. Now by $\land$-elimination you derive :  $\lnot p \lor r$ and with $p$, by *disjuctive syllogism*, conclude with $r$.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will look over this to understand. Also, I see the rule "premises" in my book a few times is it a certain rule or an assumption? Basically I mean how do you get "p" from "(p∨q)→r"? Is there a rule u follow for that certain case? Thats the only thing that really confuses me thanks.'

Comment: @geforce - the "general form" of an argument id : from $\alpha$ and $\beta$, conclude with $\gamma$. We call formulae $\alpha, \beta$ assumptions or premises and $\gamma$ conclusion. In your case 1) : $\alpha$ is $(p∨q)→r$, $\beta$ is $p$ and $\gamma$ is $r$ and we have to show that, applying logical "allowed" rules or transformation, we can derive the conclusion from the premises. You have to review the basic definitions and the set of allowed rules.

Comment: Ok thanks you're right, I will review the rules more seriously since it is important