# Predicate Logic Proof Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

I am struggling really hard with proofs I cannot seem to understand them at all no matter how hard i try. I'm thinking of getting a tutor because questions like this I just give up and fail on. Any hints or help would be appreciate, thanks.

***Question:***

Decide whether the inferences are valid in each case. Give the reason behind each
step. Do not use truth tables in this question.

∀x ∈ ℝ, p(x) v q(x)

a ∈ ℝ

q(a) -> r(a)

.'. p(a) v r(a)

***My Solution which is incorrect***
>

∀x ∈ ℝ, p(x) v q(x)               (premise)

a ∈ ℝ                              (premise)

p(a) v q(a)                         (universal instantiation from (2))

p(a)                                (using simplification (1))

q(a)                                (using simplification (2))

I don't know this line(how do i find r to get to the next step?)

q(a) -> r(a)

¬q(a) v r(a)                                    (logical equiv (7))

.'. p(a) v r(a)

Comment: The main reason you couldn't find a proof for that inference is that the inference isn't valid.  Try looking for a counterexample.

Comment: Are you sure about the 3rd premise : p(a) -> r(a) ? In order to conclude, it must be : q(a) -> r(a).

Comment: Hey I am very sorry amWhy but I did not mean to do that because I by accident did not review everything before submitting that is my fault.

Comment: Yes Mauro, I mistyped it... its supposed to be q(a) -> r(a). I don't understand how to get r from p(a) v q(a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite similar to your previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930037/predicate-logic-and-logic-proofsreview-homework-questions), case 2 : $p \rightarrow r, p \lor q, \lnot q \vdash r$.

Now we have :

> $p(a) \lor q(a), q(a) \rightarrow r(a) \vdash p(a) \lor r(a)$

1) $p \lor q$ --- 1st premise

2) $q \rightarrow r$ --- 2nd premise

3) $\lnot p \rightarrow q$ --- from 1)

4) $\lnot p \rightarrow r$ --- from 3) and 2) by *syllogism* : from $A \rightarrow B$ and $B \rightarrow C$, infer : $A \rightarrow C$

5) $p \lor r$ --- from 4) .

Comment: Hi Mauro this makes it look easier without the quantifiers or predicates. Am i able to write proofs like this if its asked in quantifier/predicate logic?

Comment: @geforce - In genral no; only in this simple case I've omitted the "a" because we have only it and no other instantiated quantifiers...

Comment: So "a ∈ ℝ" would not count as a premise? Because it is true that there is an "a" that is a member of the rational numbers?

Comment: @geforce - $\mathbb R$ is the set of *real* numbers. The 1st premise is $∀x ∈ ℝ, p(x) \lor q(x)$; thus, when we instantite it, we have to choose an $a ∈ ℝ$ to get : $p(a) \lor q(a)$. But the following steps in the proof are general ones.

Comment: Thank you very much Mauro for clearing that up. I will probably be getting a tutor for this course since I have a test next Monday and am still struggling with these proofs. You are one of the most helpful users on this site and I thank you very much for that.